# UNITY - Player Controller Not Moving Toward Mouse Cursor

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine

I want the player controller to move towards the mouse pointer on the screen. Trying to figure out raycasting, and have managed to debug the global coordinates of my mouse position.. However I am struggling to figure out why my player is shooting up into the y direction.. At first I figured it was down to my camera position, as when I tried this before, the coords were static. So I specifically set a reference to my players position to see if it was that, which was the problem, but still flies up into the sky.. I have tried addForce with a rigidbody which kinda worked, but was only working on the y rotation, for whatever reason. I have tried transform.position to test the code, which worked,  but still had issues of shooting off in the Y direction, and have used Vector3.MoveTowards and Vector3.Lerp in transform.translate... everything with the same issue,  I click play, as soon as my raycast hits, the gameobject shoot into the air, until I get a console error, saying too far away.

```
public class MousePlayerController : MonoBehaviour
{

    public float speed = 10f; 
    private Camera cam;
    private Rigidbody playerRb;
    private Vector3 playerPos;
    private float heightLimit = 0.5f;
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        cam = Camera.main;
        playerRb = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        playerPos = GameObject.Find("Player").transform.position;
        Ray mousePos = cam.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);
        RaycastHit rayLength;
       
        if(Physics.Raycast(mousePos, out rayLength, Mathf.Infinity)) {
            Debug.Log(rayLength.point);
            Debug.DrawLine(mousePos.origin, rayLength.point, Color.blue);
            transform.Translate(Vector3.Lerp(playerPos, rayLength.point, speed * Time.deltaTime));
            //transform.position = Vector3.Lerp(playerPos, rayLength.point, speed * Time.deltaTime);
            //playerRb.AddForce(rayLength.point * speed * Time.deltaTime);
            if (transform.position.y > 1f) {
                //playerPos = new Vector3(transform.position.x, heightLimit, transform.position.z);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So `cam.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition)` gives a point in 3d space, however we only care about the 2d cordinate, so we can simply discard the Y component

```
// get mouse position
Vector3 mousePos = Camera.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition);

// discard y
mousePos = new Vector3(mousePos.x, 0, mousePos.z);

// we can then use this
transform.Translate(Vector3.Lerp(playerPos, mousePos, speed * Time.deltaTime));
```

Hope this solves your problem